# Rails Webpack Vue '__webpack_require__(...) is not a function' Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js

I'm getting this error after I run '/bin/webpack-dev-server' and make any changes to .vue files. When I first run the server everything works fine, it's only after I make changes that this error gets thrown. On a side note changes to the hello_vue.js file do not flash this error and they do show.

The files gets recompiled successfully in the system terminal too when the dev-server is running. I've added nothing out of the ordinary to the application as this is a new project.

The guide at https://github.com/rails/webpacker was used to get webpacker up and running.

Could this be a turbolinks error?

Any help is appreciated!

hello_vue.js

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import App from './app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#hello',
    data: {
      message: "Can you say hello?"
    },
    components: { App }
  })
})
```

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <center>
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
      <button type="button" name="button" @click="addOne">Click me!</button>
      <p>This is a number test: {{ data }}</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        message: "Hello Vue! From inside app.vue!",
        data: 5
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addOne(){
        this.data += 1
        console.log(this.data)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

consoler debugger:

```
exports = module.exports = require("../../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(undefined);
// imports


// module
exports.push([module.id, "\np[data-v-13f0f5d2] {\n  font-size: 2em;\n  text-align: center;\n}\n", ""]);

// exports



//////////////////
// WEBPACK FOOTER
// ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-13f0f5d2","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/javascript/packs/app.vue
// module id = 0
// module chunks = 0
```

browser console:

```
<anonymous> webpack-internal:///0:1:28
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:75:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///47:5:16
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:628:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///46:5:3
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:616:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///45:3:21
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///45:1:29
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:604:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///44:1:14
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:592:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///34:5:14
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///34:1:29
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:475:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:1209:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:20:12
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:63:18
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packs/hello_vue-4d561ea1e57c869e7983.js:1:11
```